# how to select values from sqlserver2008 except null values?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table called User_info. In which some columns contains values and some columns contains null values. How can I select value fields alone?

Comment: What have you tried? Is it the case that some columns contain `null`s for *all* rows and you're wanting to exclude those from the result? If so, there's no easy way to do that since any particular query always produces result sets with the same "shape" - the number, names and types of the columns in the result set is fixed.

Comment: If those columns are always null remove them from the table or at least from the select, they are useless, aren't they? If they are not always null select them or replace null with something other(f.e. `<undefined>` or an empty string). What's the problem?

Comment: In my case I want to select all the values from the table and need to bind the values to the corresponding fields again in the form. while binding, if a column contain null value then it raising an error. The error is **Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid**

Comment: @Manivel: then you know what you instead have to fix. Not the nulls are the problem but your cast. But as mentioned above you can also fix it by selecting an empty string: `Col1=IsNull(Col1,'')` or `Col1=Coalesce(Col1,'')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment:

> In my case I want to select all the values from the table and need to
>   bind the values to the corresponding fields again in the form. while
>   binding, if a column contain null value then it raising an error. The
>   error is
>
> Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid

Then you either have to show the code that causes the invalid cast or replace nulls with an empty string:

```
SELECT Col1 = COALESCE(Col1,'') 
FROM User_info u
```

Instead of [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) you could just as well use [`ISNULL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx).

Comment: how can we do this for Date? I am having DateControl. If I pass Empty String to Date control, it selects the default date as 1/1/1990.